# Cannot read directory

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, centos, php

I am using CentOS 6.3 and I am trying to `opendir` and `readdir` using PHP.

apache is in the group of the `user` and I am trying to read the `/home/user/mnt` which is mounted remotely using SSHFS.

Unfortunately, apache is not able to read this directory even if the group has execute permission.

Can I somehow fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the remote directory to a place where the Apache Server will have access.. at least, it was my problem.

`sshfs -o allow_other,uid=33,gid=33 user@server.com: /var/www/remote/`